# ImportError: No module named _caffe in windows 7

Tags: python, python-2.7, caffe, pycaffe

I downloaded caffe-windows and copied `python\caffe` folder into my site-packages. But after importing the caffe it gives me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ag185211\Desktop\Tanmay\HappyNet-master\opencv_functions.py", line 23, in 
import caffe
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\caffe_init_.py", line 1, in 
from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver, NCCL, Timer
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\caffe\pycaffe.py", line 13, in 
from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, 
ImportError: No module named _caffe
```

But in caffe folder there is `_caffe.cpp folder`. How should I solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please consider following their build/installation instructions on their [github project page](https://github.com/happynear/caffe-windows) first.

Comment: `__caffe.cpp` is only usable to a C++ compiler, not Python.  You have to compile the source and install it properly.

Comment: How do I compile the source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying folders is not installing packages. Clearly the caffe_windows package depends on a (compiled binary) [*extension module*](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html). The interpreter doesn't look in the same place for extensions as it does for pure-Python modules, and bypassing the correct installation procedure has left you with the Python code accessible but the extension module unreachable.

You should either follow the instructions for installation given on the README file in the [caffe-windows repository](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows) or use one of the pre-built binary distributions it mentions.